# Custom Change Password Form

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am just trying to modify the look of the change password page. The only thing I couldn't figure out is what is the CurrentPassword field called..

```
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, {'attr': {'class': 'txtRegisterEmail','placeholder': 'Password'} }) }}
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second,{'attr': {'class': 'txtRegisterEmail','placeholder': 'Verify password'} }) }}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in [ChangePasswordFormType](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Form/Type/ChangePasswordFormType.php#L33-L38), it's called `current_password`:

```
{{ form_widget(form.current_password) }}
```

So in order, you'd have:

```
{{ form_widget(form.current_password) }}
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}
```